# Linear layout dividing programmatically

Tags: java, android

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
{
    ChildLayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    ChildLayout.setWeightSum(100);
    ChildLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    ChildLayout.setId(i);

    Prd_txt = new TextView(getActivity());
    Prd_txt.setId(c.getInt(3));
    ProdStr_All.add(c.getString(4));
    ProdTxt_All.add(Prd_txt);
    Prd_txt.setPadding(8, 0, 0, 0);

    edit_phy = new EditText(getActivity());
    edit_phyAll.add(edit_phy);
    edit_phy.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    edit_phy.setId(Dist_cat[k]);
    edit_phy.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    edit_trn = new EditText(getActivity());
    edit_trnAll.add(edit_trn);
    edit_trn.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    edit_trn.setId(Dist_cat[k]);
    edit_trn.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    Total=new TextView((getActivity()));
    tot_all.add(Total);
    Total.setId(k);
    Total.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    Total.setTextSize((global_variables.ConvertPixels(getActivity(), 19)));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,50);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,16);

    ChildLayout.addView(Prd_txt, 0,layoutParams2);
    ChildLayout.addView(edit_phy, 1,layoutParams3);
    ChildLayout.addView(edit_trn, 2,layoutParams3);
    ChildLayout.addView(Total, 3,layoutParams3);
    if(i%2==0) 
    {
        ChildLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colortablelight);
    }else
    {
          ChildLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colortablemedium);
    }

    MainLayout.addView(ChildLayout,layoutParams);
                   c.moveToNext();
}

for(int m=0;m<ProdTxt_All.size();m++)
{
     ProdTxt_All.get(m).setText(ProdStr_All.get(m));
}
```

output:
[image: output]

Problem:
I want to divide my linear layout in fixed size of Product weightsum 50 and rest 
16 but could not achieve that, Tried to add height and width, but in different resolution it shows differently. So tried for weightsum. How to solve?

Comment: Before giving downvote,Please tell me where i went wrong.So that i can understand.

Comment: You should first state the question, then show the code and highlight the part of code which is incorrect/buggy/faulty/ or thats not doing what you intend, then add some smart words so nobody gets upset :)

Comment: You should definitely use the PercentRelativeLayout, heres a blog post on how to set it up http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en

Comment: @Arlind Sorry for bad english!thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

@Rashmi S
What is the problem doing that on XML? since its easier to handle especially with UI Designer software or  what you called that and its more cleaner from the perspective of maintainability and readability. Thats only my opinion, in case you got some reason to do that, possibly there's an alternative aproach.

Comment: ,the products are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

By using `WRAP_CONTENT` and `weight` at the same time, `LinearLayout` will calculate and prepare enough space for content before taking care of the `weight`. That's why sometimes you see this warning when setup views inside design layout with `xml`.

[image]

To ensure the parent view separates childs by weight properly, setup **height = 0 (VERTICAL)** as well as **width = 0 (HORIZONTAL)** before weight.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,50);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,16);
```